# Subdomain suddenly stopped working on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos7, httpd.conf

We have a server on CentOS 7.4 which runs multiple websites and subdomains.
A domain say `xyz.example.com` is pointing to xyz folder in html root which is working since last 4 years and suddenly stopped working yesterday night and is now showing the Apache landing page.

Here is what I tried so far,

1. Checked httpd.conf file, and no change has been made to this file since last 2 months
2. Checked directory for files and all the files are present, no file has been modified
3. Checked for DNS records and A record is pointing to the same IP

The other websites and subdomains are working perfectly fine, but only this subdomain stopped working.

**Note:** Due to an online event yesterday, that subdomain had heavy traffic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the web server configuration.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen you mean the httpd.conf file? I am sorry I am  a programmer and not a server level guy